# Why do my elements only get padding on the top?

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to style a "toolbar" for my website.  I have three links: About, Support, Contact on the left side and social icons on the right.  Both are structured with unordered lists.  For whatever reason, the padding from the #toolbar element is only applied to the top of the UL's.  I'm not really sure what's going on.  Could it be related to the positions of the elements?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BaseCMD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: url(img/argyle.png);
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #999;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            a:link, a:active, a:visited {
                color: #b71f2f;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover {
                color: #999;
            }
            header {
                background: rgb(69,72,77); /* Old browsers */
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(69,72,77,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            }
            header #toolbar {
                background: #000;
                border-radius: 5px;
                border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #666;
                padding: 10px;
                position: relative;
            }
            header #toolbar > ul.info {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
            }
            header #toolbar > ul.info > li {
                display: inline;
                border-right: 1px solid #666;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
            header #toolbar ul.info > li > a:link, header #toolbar ul.info > li > a:active, header #toolbar ul.info > li > a:visited {
                color: #999;
                text-decoration: none;
            }   
            header #toolbar ul.social {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
            }
            header #toolbar ul.social > li {
                display: inline;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
            header #banner {
                padding: 25px;
            }
            header #logo {
                float: left;
            }
            header #logo a.logo {
                background: url(img/Logo.png) no-repeat;
                width: 176px;
                height: 80px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 25px 0;
                display: block;
            }
            header #advert {
                float: right;
            }   
            header nav {
                border-top: 1px solid #333333;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
                margin-top: 25px;
                padding: 10px;
                box-shadow:         0px -5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            header nav > ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0px auto;
            }
            header nav > ul > li {
                display: inline;
            }   
            header nav > ul > li > a:link, header nav > ul > li > a:visited, header nav > ul > li > a:active, header nav > ul > li > a:hover  {
                color: #777;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #454545;
                margin-right: 15px;
                padding: 10px 15px;
            }
            header nav > ul > li > a:hover {
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
                background: rgba(183, 31, 47, 0.25);            
            }   
            ul.dropdown-menu {
                background: #111;
            }
            ul.dropdown-menu a:link, ul.dropdown-menu a:active, ul.dropdown-menu a:visited {
                color: #666;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            ul.dropdown-menu a:hover {
                color: #999;
                text-decoration: none;
                background: none;
            }
            .alert {
                margin-top: 25px;
            }           
            #content {
                background: #151515;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                border-radius: 10px;
                margin: 25px 0px;
                padding: 15px;
                min-height: 100%;
            }           
            #bgSwitch {
                background: #111;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 20%;
                z-index: 1000;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                text-align: center;
                width: 200px;
            }
            #bgSwitch h1 {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #333;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 10px 0px;
            }
            #bgSwitch > ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #bgSwitch > ul > li {
                padding: 5px 0px;
                width: 45%;
                float: left;
                display: inline;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            #bgSwitch > ul > li > img {
                width: 32px;
                height: 32px;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            .advert-blank {
                width: 468px;
                height: 60px;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #222;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #444;
            }
            .advert-blank p {
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 10px 0;
                color: #666;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <section id="toolbar" class="container">
                    <ul class="info">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/twitter.png" border="0" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/digg.png" border="0" alt="Digg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/rss.png" border="0" alt="RSS"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icons/vimeo.png" border="0" alt="Vimeo"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section id="banner">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="advert">
                        <div class="advert-blank"><p>We see you have an ad-blocker.  Turning it off will help keep us running!</p></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <nav>
                    <ul class="dropdown container">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Articles</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                <li><a href="#">Nintendo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">PlayStation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">PC Gaming</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Xbox</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <section id="content">
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5b5wa9w/)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the two `ul` tags in your navbar both have their position set to absolute, which takes them out of the document flow and leaves your tool bar without a computable height.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/q5b5wa9w/3/

All I did was float the lists left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Never answered a question on here before so go easy.  But you have your header #toolbar > ul.info  and header #toolbar ul.social are positioned absolute.  When you position them absolute, you are removing it from the Document flow.

I would remove the positioning and use floats paired with a clearfix like [Seen here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Float the two ul's, one left and the other right(per your design), and apply .cf to the wrapping container.

Answer (score 0):

change the padding rule under header #toolbar to 0px like so:

```
header #toolbar {
            background: #000;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666;
            padding: 0px;<-- this line here
            position: relative;
        }
```